Multibounty feature?
I would like to add a bounty for a question to make it more attractive.
But I can't, because someone else set a bounty.
Conceptually I see no problem if I add my bounty to the question to reflect the higher interest in form of a Superbounty or Multibounty.
I like to add following example: "A user awards 50 bounty to a question. 10 other users like the question and think it deserves more bounty so it be answered more likely." -> Currently, the bounty would be 50 while the actual interest is rather >200. So this question is undervalued. If every user can only award 50 and needs to wait for a week for the previous bounty to vest, the question may remain unanswered and undervalued for the entire time.
The easiest way would be to let users just add their bounty leaving all else equal (the original bounty offerer still distributes the entire bounty).
Can you please add the feature for multiple bounties?
Thanks.

Btw why Quant SE specifically rather than the whole SE?

I'm not really sure I see the point of allowing multiple bounties on a given question at once. Bounties are used to draw more attention to a question: they get put in the "featured" questions tab, and the title appears with the bounty amount in all question lists it's contained in. Multiple bounties won't actually increase the visibility of the post.

@emcor I don't think a certain amount of additional bounty will give that much additional incentive to answer a question.

@BCLC I am pretty sure if you compare questions with different bounties the most and best answers are given to the highest bounties.

Sorry for the confusion @emcor. What I meant was that if we offer a bounty of +50, it will give a certain amount of incentive say 100 (no idea what units to use). If someone else offers more +50, will the amount of incentive reach 200? Even 150? I think something along 110.

Laura, I think emcor's idea is to give more incentive to answer the question. For instance, I see a +50 bounty question but am not so interested in answering. Then again if it is +100, my interest in answering may increase. If you're thinking that such interest increase may not be that much, I agree and that is my point.
